# get content body, title from a handful of drupal nodes

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am creating a mobile version of my Drupal website and I need some snippets that will grab the title and body for nodes 1 2 and 5 and print them out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the version of Drupal you're using so I'll assume v7:

```
$nids = array(1, 2, 5);
foreach (node_load_multiple($nids) as $node) {
  echo '<h2>' . check_plain($node->title) . '</h2>';
  echo $node->body[$node->language][0]['body_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will work fine if your use case is really just limited to the node IDs you want to display, you know the Node IDs, and they won't change. If, on the other hand, you want to display title and body fields for nodes of a certain content type or associated with a particular term (i.e. you might have more node IDs later, so your use case is dynamic), you'd do well to just use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), which is available for Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 and wouldn't require any custom code.